# Lua How to pass a void* pointer to lua in C++ && pass it back to C++

Tags: pointers, lua, luabind

Now I want to pass a `void*` pointer to Lua, use userdata?
How to do this?

BTW, I used luabind, but it cannot pass a `void*` pointer to Lua stack, this is annoying! Could you guys help me?

```cpp
struct Event
{
     A* a;
     B* b;
     ...
};

Event *e;
void* instance = (void*)e;


// param is a parameter that is passed from Lua script. param is a Event object. And I cast it into a void* type
string Answer(void* param)
{
    WorkEvent *pWorkEvent = static_cast<WorkEvent*>(param);
    ASSERT_RET(pWorkEvent, NULL);

    string call_id = pWorkEvent->GetCallId();
    CCmThreadManager::TType thrd_id =  pWorkEvent->GetHandleThrdID();
    Coroutine *pco    = pWorkEvent->m_pco;
```

Comment: What did you try? Show your code please. And which version of `lua` on which system?

Comment: string Answer(void* param)
{
    WorkEvent *pWorkEvent = static_cast<WorkEvent*>(param);
    ASSERT_RET(pWorkEvent, NULL);

    string call_id = pWorkEvent->GetCallId();
    CCmThreadManager::TType thrd_id =  pWorkEvent->GetHandleThrdID();
    Coroutine *pco    = pWorkEvent->m_pco;

Comment: Please edit your question and put your code in the question, not in comments.

Comment: I have posted the related codes.

Comment: Have you tried reading [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/28.5.html)? Then, why would you want to pass a void* when you use LuaBind? LuaBind is there so that you can safely manipulate C++ Objects from Lua.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's answer your actual question before getting into why you shouldn't be doing this.

LuaBind is a tool for binding C++ functions and objects to Lua. A `void*` is neither a function nor an object. It is, quite literally, a pointer to *nothing*. As such, it has no real meaning to LuaBind. So you cannot pass one directly.

You *can* however return a `luabind::object`, which can represent any Lua value. For example, a Lua userdata. Which means you can create some light userdata from your `void*`, stick it into a `luabind::object` and return it from a function you register with LuaBind.

```
luabind::object RegisteredFunction(..., lua_State *L)
{
  void *return_value = ...;

  lua_pushlightuserdata(L, return_value);
  luabind::object ret(luabind::from_stack(L, -1));
  lua_pop(L, 1);
  return ret;
}
```

To allow Lua to pass it back so that you can retrieve it, simply create a function that takes a luabind::object as the `void*` parameter:

```
void OtherRegisteredFunction(..., luabind::object obj, ...)
{
  assert(luabind::type(obj) == LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA);
  obj.push();
  void *param = lua_touserdata(obj.interpreter(), -1);
  lua_pop(obj.interpreter(), 1);
}
```

So that's how you pass that kind of data. Now here's why you shouldn't do that.

First, your code is *broken*:

```
WorkEvent *pWorkEvent = static_cast<WorkEvent*>(param);
```

Assuming that your `param` came from this line, `void* instance = (void*)e`, C++ doesn't guarantee this to work. If you cast an object to a `void*`, C++ *only* provides a guarantee of getting something useful back if you cast it to *the exact same object* as it was before.

You started with an `Event*`, then converted it to a `void*`. The only *legal* operation you can do is to cast it back to an `Event*`. Even if `WorkEvent` is a derived class of `Event`, you cannot cast it *directly* to that class. You have to turn it back into an `Event*` first. Also, you should use a `dynamic_cast` to do the down-cast once you have an `Event*`.

Second, stop using `void*`s for this. If all of your events are derived from `Event*`, then just pass an `Event*` and use `dynamic_cast` where appropriate. If they aren't, then you should be [using `boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/any.html) (LuaBind requires Boost, so obviously you're using it already). Not only will you be able to bind that to LuaBind (since it's an actual type), it's much more natural to work with.

And it has built-in protection from exactly the problem your code had before; if you tried to cast it to a `WorkEvent` when it was given only an `Event`, it would throw an exception.

Comment: Ok, I get it. I have to find another way to solve my problem. Thank U.

Answer (score 2):

We don't use void* in lua directly.
Here we use c function to call lua function then  lua function to  call c function
in the 1st c  we  pass a void* to lua function
then lua pass the void* to 2nd c function.

But we find that  we can't pass a void* to lua 
when we add the default_converter void*.

```
namespace luabind
{
    template <>
    struct default_converter<void*> : native_converter_base<void*>
    {
        static int compute_score(lua_State * L, int index)
        {
            // this function will return 0 or -1 (int)
            return lua_type(L, index) == LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA ? 0 : -1;
        }
        void* from(lua_State * L, int index)
        {
            return lua_touserdata(L, index);
        }
        void to(lua_State * L, void* value)
        {
            lua_pushlightuserdata(L, value);
        }
    };

} // namespace luabind
```